# How to OVerride the PricebookEntry Edit page

Tags: visualforce, pricebook, button-overrides

I wanna open my custom VF page when I click the edit button form the pricebookEntry page.

is this possible?

Please give me the guide.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define custom button/link, point it to your custom VF page.
http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=defining_custom_links.htm&language=en_US

Set content source to URl 
../apex/{yourVFpage}?id={!PricebookEntry.Id}

Upon investigation i came to know that you cannot add custom button for pricebook.
You have to come up with List Details and Edit Custom Pages for your solution. Also  you can add a custom tab too.

Comment: In where i can find the edit button of the pricebookentry view page?

Comment: You need to hide that button from pagelayout and add new custom button. Follow the link to add new button.

Comment: Am asking in where i have to create the button for prickebookentry page. because i just open the pricebook entry object page. but it doesnt shown the button.

Comment: Please read my updated answer.

Comment: List Details and Edit Custom Pages means? In where i have to open that list view?

Comment: What Shanker is saying (and I agree) in order to control what buttons are displayed to the user you will need to create a custom visualforce page to replace the existing default page. You will need to create a custom tab that navigates to a custom 'list view' page that then navigates to your new custom 'edit' page.